# Find backslash (\) in a string --Python

Tags: python, backslash

How can I compare if a backslash is in my string?

I don't know how to write the backslash symbol to compare it.
I try this but don't work:

Code:

```
s = r"\""
print s
```

Output: `\"`

If I try `s = "\""` it gives `"` as output

I don't know how to acheive that.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash.

```
s = "\\"
```

Comment: to add to this the reason it gives " as the output is because you are escaping the " character.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>>mystring = "can python find this backslash \n"
>>>"\\" in r"%r" % mystring
True
```

while trying to filter the backslash \ character from being used in Windows filenames I searched a lot of places for answers. this is the solution worked for me.
based on information I read at...
http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/

Answer (score 3):

Backslashes are used for escaping, so to display a backslash in a string literal you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

```
print "\\"
```

prints a string with 1 backslash.

Answer (score 2):

```
"\\" in mystring
```

Where mystring is your string.  Will tell you if it contains a backslash