# Divide string data into list of lists by finding /r/n substring

Tags: python, string, special-characters, python-3.6

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Do I need to treat the \ as a special character? The sequence \r\n appears literally in the string in the txt file I am using.

```
def split_into_rows(weather_data):
    list_of_rows = []

    while not (weather_data.find("\r\n") == -1):
        firstreturnchar = weather_data.find("\r\n")
        row = weather_data[ :firstreturnchar]
        list_of_rows = list_of_rows.append(row)

    return list_of_rows
```

What I need is, while there are still examples of the substring \r\n left in the string, to find the first instance of the substring "\r\n", chop everything before that and put it into the variable row, then append row to list_of_rows.

Comment: `list_of_rows = list_of_rows.append(row)`: this doesn't require an assignment, lists are mutable

Comment: Note that you can do just that via `weather_data.splitlines()`

Comment: You need to escape the backslash (type another backslash in front). `\r` and `\n` are both special characters. See [this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331778/find-backslash-in-a-string-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `split()`:

```
def split_into_rows(weather_data):

    return weather_data.split('\\r\\n')
```

Comment: That works! except I still need to escape the special char with def split_into_rows(weather_data):
    return weather_data.split('\\r\\n')